# I cannot install Ubuntu on my laptop

Tags: dual-boot, dell, uefi

I bought a Dell Inspiron 5423 ultrabook with a 32GB SSD drive and a 500GB HDD. I tried to install Ubuntu with a live CD, but there is no drive shown on which to install Ubuntu. In my boot options I changed the boot option from UEFI to Legacy. I also changed the SATA option to ATA, but it's still not working.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of that question; I believe it's a hardware problem (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

If by "no drive shown" you mean that the Ubuntu installer isn't giving you options for any hard disk device at all (no `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`), then you've probably got hardware that's too new, and there are no Linux drivers for it. If so, then I'm afraid the only solution is to wait for updated Linux drivers. Such drivers might actually exist already, and you might want to try Fedora or some other distribution in the hopes that they're distributing them; or if you're more technically inclined, you could try compiling the latest kernel and using it with the Ubuntu installer.

If you mean something else, though, please clarify. If necessary, take a digital photo of the screen(s) that illustrate the problem and post links. (Edit your original question to do this.)